# Allow GET requests ony from specific domains by using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, referer

How can I allow GET requests only from specific domains by using htaccess in a more reliable way than using Referer (which can be manipulated).

Current, imperfect, solution:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer domain\.com ALLOWED_DOMAIN
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=ALLOWED_DOMAIN
```

The soluton can be also based on IP of a domain (not the user's machine).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LIMIT` directive in your htaccess instead this way.

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from domain.com anotherone.com onemore.com
</Limit>
```

Let me know if this answer works for you.

Comment: Thanks Panama Jack. Perhaps I was not clear enough. I do have a piece of JavaScript code placed on multiple domains (domainA.com on serverA, domainB.com on serverB etc.) which produces AJAX calls to a php file located on my own server (serverC). I need to allow requests for this php file coming only from domainA.com, domainB.com etc. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I believe I understand and that rule should still work. you just need to put this code on serverC htaccess and put the `allow from domainA.com domainB.com`. This will only allow GET/POST requests coming from those domains as you requested in the OP.

Comment: I've tried the code but unfortunately i still could see 403 status in the console for the domainA.com. I've tried also using the domain name with "www." but that didn't help. I've tried to put my own IP instead of the domainA.com and that allowed the calls. Unfortunately, that's not what I need.

Comment: Try the IP address of the domain instead of using the hostname.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either (console showed 403 status for the calls).